# Using Malayalam language word in imagettftext()

Tags: php

I am trying to convert Malayalam(Indian language) words to image using php `imagettftext()` function. I am using Malayalam font as well. Here is a block of code I am using.

```
// malayalam word
$utf8str = "കറുപ്പ്";

// buffer output in case there are errors
ob_start();

// create blank image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400,40);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im,255,255,255);
imagefilledrectangle($im,0,0,imagesx($im),imagesy($im),$white);

// write the text to image
$font = "anjali.ttf";
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, 50, 50, 50, 0); // dark gray
$size = 20;
$angle = 0;
$x = 5;
$y = 25;
imagettftext($im, $size, $angle, $x, $y , $color, $font, $utf8str);

// display the image, if no errors
$err = ob_get_clean();
if( !$err ) {
    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($im);
}
```

With this code, I get the following output

[image]

I have tried many Malayalam fonts and codes from stackoverflow. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: I can't speak Malayalam so your string (`കറുപ്പ്`) and your picture look identical to me. What's wrong exactly?

Comment: If you take a look again, joined letters are not displaying correctly. `പ് പ്` should be `പ്പ്`.

Comment: How about drawing text into an HTML5 `canvas`? http://jsfiddle.net/JUWrV/972/

Comment: For Arabic joining you need to use AR-PHP, I guess there should be something for Malayalam as well or you can try and fork the Arabic into Malayalam supporting variant: http://www.ar-php.org/

Comment: @Yaron, I am looking for a php solution as I have other things to add on image. And AR-PHP couldnt help.

Comment: As I said I'm not familiar with that alphabet. You mean that `പ്പ്` should display as a single character, right? I suspect the problem is that my OS and browser are configured for Spanish so plain text is also rendered incorrectly for me (but you're seeing it correctly). ---- Is [this](http://i.imgur.com/vj7ggod.png) the expected output?

Comment: You are right, the output you have linked is the right one. Any idea?

Comment: In the end, PHP just relies on a [third-party library](https://www.freetype.org/). As you can see from heir changelong they're still adding new languages. It's possible that Malayalam  is just not supported. I'm sorry, I don't really have further suggestions.

Comment: Do you know any other option to convert a string to image regardless of font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research, I came to know that existing malayalam fonts does not support all the characters. We will have to wait for new fonts to come up that support all the characters.